# Remove closest link with specific class using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two links, one for "Add Role" and second one "Remove Role". I want to use jQuery to change color of "remove role" link when "add role" click. I have managed most of it and remaining function but I am missing something to find closed with class SelectRoleLinkToRemove to change color of that link only NOT others. These add and remove link and each row in grid.

```
<div class="ob_gCc1">
    <div class="ob_gCc2">
        <a class="SelectRoleLink" id="" href="#" style="color: red;"> Add Role</a>
        <a class="SelectRoleLinkToRemove HiddenField" id="" href="#"> Remove Role</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ob_gCd"></div>
</div>
```

### jQuery

```
$(".SelectRoleLink").on("click", function () {

    var selectedRoleID = $(this).attr("id");

    $(this).css("color", "red");

    $(this).closest(".SelectRoleLinkToRemove").css("color", "green");

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`closest` will search for the closest **ancestor**. Use `siblings` to remove sibling of the current element.

**Note:** You can also use `next` if the element you want to select is immediate next element of the clicked element. If not immediate next, you can also use `nextAll`.

```
$(this).siblings(".SelectRoleLinkToRemove").css("color", "green");
```

**Demo**

```js
$(".SelectRoleLink").on("click", function() {
  var selectedRoleID = $(this).attr("id");
  $(this).css("color", "red");
  $(this).siblings(".SelectRoleLinkToRemove").css("color", "green");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ob_gCc1">
  <div class="ob_gCc2">
    <a class="SelectRoleLink" id="" href="#" style="color: red;"> Add Role</a>
    <a class="SelectRoleLinkToRemove HiddenField" id="" href="#"> Remove Role</a>
  </div>
  <div class="ob_gCd"></div>
</div>
<div class="ob_gCc1">
  <div class="ob_gCc2">
    <a class="SelectRoleLink" id="" href="#" style="color: red;"> Add Role</a>
    <a class="SelectRoleLinkToRemove HiddenField" id="" href="#"> Remove Role</a>
  </div>
  <div class="ob_gCd"></div>
</div>
```

You can use following optimized solution:

1. `selectedRoleID` is not used. Can be removed.
2. No need of changing the color of clicked link to red, as it is already applied
3. Use classes instead of inline styles
4. Use `event.preventDefault()` or `return false` in event handler.

```js
$(".SelectRoleLink").on("click", function(e) {
  $(this).siblings(".SelectRoleLinkToRemove").addClass('green');

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.green {
  color: green;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ob_gCc1">
  <div class="ob_gCc2">
    <a class="SelectRoleLink red" id="" href="#"> Add Role</a>
    <a class="SelectRoleLinkToRemove HiddenField" id="" href="#"> Remove Role</a>
  </div>
  <div class="ob_gCd"></div>
</div>
<div class="ob_gCc1">
  <div class="ob_gCc2">
    <a class="SelectRoleLink red" id="" href="#"> Add Role</a>
    <a class="SelectRoleLinkToRemove HiddenField" id="" href="#"> Remove Role</a>
  </div>
  <div class="ob_gCd"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".SelectRoleLink").on("click", function () {

    var selectedRoleID = $(this).attr("id");

    $(this).css("color", "red");

    $(this).next().css("color", "green");

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mgny3nze/)
One option is using `.next()`

Answer (score 1):

Another way to go about this is to add a `selected` class to the `Add Role` button and use CSS to style the `Remove Role` button.

```
// Javascript
$(".SelectRoleLink").on("click", function () {
   var isSelected = $(this).hasClass('selected');
   if(isSelected) {
     $(this).removeClass('selected');
   } else {
     $(this).addClass('selected');
   }
}
```

and style it accordingly

```
/* CSS */
a.selected {
  color: red;
}

a.selected + .SelectRoleLinkToRemove {
  color: green;
}
```